# Which HTML event listener should I use?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page that interacts with two servlets and consists therefore of two forms. First form sends data to servlet one to prepare some data to fill drop down menus in the second form depending on the selection. Second form holds four drop down menus which represent different attributes of an object (and interacts with servlet two).

Not all combinations of selections from the drop down menus are valid in step two, therefore I want to show some texts beneath the drop downs to make the user aware of invalid combinations. I used `onchange="checkValues()"` to generate these texts, which works fine per se. (`onsubmit()` later prevents invalid combinations from submitting)

**The Problem**: Unfortunately, the preset combination is an invalid one. I want to show the texts also, when second form is loaded for the first time. I tried to use `onsubmit="checkValues()"` in form one, but it has no influence on the texts as the drop down menus (and therefore the values to be checked) are loaded after the submit.

Which event would be more appropriate to cover `onchange` and **the first combination after initialization** of the drop downs?

Use an other preset combination is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to wrap your site in a single div and attach a single event listener to that div.

Then you can listen to everything without having to make a ton of different event listeners and slowing down your site. You can tell where it came from by evaluating the ID as long as you set one, of course

Comment: So, I could put a onchange on that div to show the texts? But how could it evaluate the combination of the dropdowns if they are not present at first (only after submission of form one)? Wouldn't I get a nullpointer exeption (or whatever the equivalent in JS is)?

Comment: would it work if I put only form two in such a div and check for onload() / onchange() event on it?

Comment: More likely you'd want to evaluate using `onSubmit`

Comment: I use onSubmit() of second form to check if the combination is okay, this works fine. I just want to make the user aware before submission, to give him instant hints how to choose or what to change and so on,... that they don't have to click 'calculate' for each try...